# Understanding javascript DOM core ideas: nodeList vs HTMLElement objects

Tags: javascript, dom, tree-traversal, nodelist

I have been working towards understanding the DOM very thoroughly. At the moment i'm making my way trough traversing the DOM tree and i seem to be finding some inconsistencies.

- On a nodeList i can use an index to iterate trough the list
- On a HTMLElement i can't use an index

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/4/

So the question is, why is it that the nodeList has an indexable list like element[0], element[1](http://jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/5) and the HTMLElement has not?

Could someone explain this to me very thoroughly? Thx...

```
<ul id="jow">
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>    
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Item</a></li> 
    <li class="active"><a href="">Item</a></li> 
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ieps"></div>
```

```js
function simple(){

    var li = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
    var ul = li[0].parentNode;
    var getULchild = ul.children[0];

    var ieps = document.getElementById("ieps");

    ieps.innerHTML += "ul will return = " + ul + "<br>";
    ieps.innerHTML += "li will return = " + li + "<br><br>";        

    ieps.innerHTML += "ul[0] will return: " + ul[0] + "<br>";
    ieps.innerHTML += "li[0] will return: " + li[0] + "<br><br>";

}
```

Also, in the fiddle, if i remove 1 of the li's containg the class "active". This will still return a nodeList and not a single HTMLElement: [jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/5](http://jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/5)

Comment: Because `NodeList` is an Array(-like) *class* holding `HTMLElement`s? `HTMLElement` is just for single nodes, not lists.

Comment: A `NodeList` is an Array-like object holding some amount of nodes. An `HTMLElement` is the element itself; it's an object of which its value is the element itself and it contains no other elements. Trying to use Array-like indices on it would be like trying to do `document.querySelectorAll(".active")[0][0];`

Comment: Then, how can i get the ul as a nodeList?

Comment: Also, in the fiddle, if i remove 1 of the li's containg the class "active". This will still return a nodeList and not the single HTMLElement. http://jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i did some research and i now have a full understanding of what objects the DOM returns when traversing the document tree. Since i didn't find any real answers on the net i'm going to give the answer to my own question, hope this helps someone else too.

---

### Retrieving element nodes

You can retrieve element nodes via 1 of these options. This will either return a `HTMLElement` or a `nodeList`.

### Methods to retrieve element nodes:

- `HTMLElement` document.getElementById()
- `HTMLCollection` document.getElementsByTagName()
- `nodeList` document.getElementsByName()
- `nodeList` document.getElementsByClassName()
- `HTMLElement` document.querySelector()
- `nodeList` document.querySelectorAll()

### nodeList vs HTMLElement

- `nodeList` can contain `1 or more` elements
- `HTMLElement` can contain `only 1` element

They are different in the way you work with them. In the nodeList you have to use brackets [] with an index value to get to items in the list nodeList[2]. Whereas with the HTMLElement you allready work with the item itself.

### Example

```
var linkClass = document.getElementsByClassName(".active");
var linkID = document.getElementById("id");

var parentFromLinkClass = linkClass[0].parentElement;
var parentFromLink = linkID.parentElement;

document.write(linkClass[0]); //returns the url of the link
document.write(linkID); //returns the url of the link

document.write(parentFromLinkClass); //HTMLLIElement (not a nodeList)
document.write(parentFromLink); //HTMLLIElement (not a nodeList)
```

- `linkClass` selects elements using a `nodeList selector function` (getElementsByClassName)
- `linkID` selects an element using an `single element selector function` (getElementByID)

### DOM semantics

The DOM semantics have a **very subtle way** of telling you what type of object it will return. Remember that the type of object returned depends on the number of elements you can 'maximum' select.

- getElementsByClassName - plural form of Element (Elements) - `returns nodeList`
- getElementByID - single form or noun of Element - `returns HTMLElement`
- querySelectorAll - selects 'all' - `returns nodeList`
- querySelector - selects 'single' - `returns HTMLElement`
- linkID.parentElement - single form or noun of Element - `returns HTMLElement`

I will update this answer when needed...

Comment: hello @kevinius, so `nodeList` can contain 1 or more elements and `HTMLElement` can contain only 1 element, what about `HTMLCollection`? can you explain, please?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, not a NodeList